# Density of Random Variables - Probability

Tags: probability

Let X be a random variable with X ~ R(0,1). Density of X is given by:

$f_{X}(x) = \begin{cases}
1  &  x \in ]0,1[  \\
0 & \text{otherwise}  \\
\end{cases}$

1) Find the density for $Y = X^2$

The answer should be $ f_{Y}(y)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}, y\in]0,1[ $ from what i'm told.
Please explain how i make this conclusion. Also if you could explain the part with ~R(0,1). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is a straightforward application of the "change of variable" formula to derive densities of functions of random variables. If you are not familiar, look it up and you will be able to derive the result yourself immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $R(0,1)$ is a little strange, the usual notation is something like $U(0,1)$, for *uniform*.

We will find the density function of $Y$. We choose the slightly long way to do it. (There is a short more mechanical way.)

First we find the **cumulative distribution function** $F_Y(y)$ of $Y$, then we differentiate to find the density function $f_Y(y)$.

First we do the easy part. Recall that $F_Y(y)=\Pr(Y\le y)$. This is $0$ for $y\le 0$, and $1$ when $y\ge 1$. Next we deal with the interesting part, when $0\lt y\lt 1$. We have
$$\Pr(Y\le y)=\Pr(X^2\le y)=\Pr(0\lt X\lt \sqrt{y})=\sqrt{y}.$$

Thus $F_Y(y)=\sqrt{y}$ when $0\lt y\lt 1$.

Finally, differentiate $F_Y(y)$ to get the density. We get $f_Y(y)=0$ if $y\le 0$ or if $y\ge 1$, and $f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}$ when $0\lt y\lt 1$.

Comment: The R in $R(0,1)$ probably stands for rectangular distribution - another name for the uniform distribution.

Comment: @StefanHansen Thanks for the explanation, I was wondering what R was standing for.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to start with the distribution function of X, given by F_X(x) = 0 for x<0, F_X(x) = x for 0 <=x <= 1 and F_X(x) = 1 for x > 1.

Then realise that F_X(x) = Prob(X<=x).

Now we want to know F_Y (y) so that we can work out its density function.

This means we need to work out, for each y, Prob(Y<=y) = Prob (X^2<=y) = Prob (X <= sqrt(y))

We need not worry about signs ONLY because we know X is non-negative. Do you see this?

...Thus we get that F_Y(y) = 0 for y<0, sqrt(y) for 0<=y<=1, and 1 for y> 1.

Differentiate this and you should get your answer.